# image upload in html page

Tags: iphone, image, upload

I am using the following code to upload an image to a web server

```
<form name="uploadFile" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validate();">

<input type="hidden" name="choice" value="upload">
<table align="center">
<tr>
    <td><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">Upload files</span></td><td><input type="file" id="ufile" name="ufile" onKeyPress="return false;" style="BACKGROUND-color:Thistle">(* jpg,gif,png)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" style="BACKGROUND-color:Thistle"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Its working fine in the browser?

But the same thing is not working in the iphone safari browser ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iPhone's Safari does not support file upload.

Comment: Is there any alternative for file upload using iPhone's safari browser ?

Answer (score 1):

http://picupapp.com/ is an app that offers code you can add to your website that will allow their iphone app to pseudo upload images to your webserver.